# What are gettext's categories?

Tags: localization, internationalization, translation, gettext

I see some thin mentions to "categories" while implementing gettext in our project, but it's still confusing...

Through the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dcgettext.php#9954), I see they're those localization constants such as `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_MONETARY`, etc.
I've seen those before when selecting localization options in my Linux machine (e.g. I use the system in US English but dates in UK English so my weeks start on Monday).

I understand they mean different categories of a localization effort, as explained in the [gettext manual itself](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#index-locale-categories), but......... the manual also states gettext is about translating strings (and thus, belongs to `LC_MESSAGES`:

> **Messages**
> The most obvious area is the language support within a locale. This is where GNU gettext provides the means for developers and users to easily change the language that the software uses to communicate to the user.

---

Thus:
**How would someone use gettext for other categories, such as time, monetary, charset or numeric?**

> *I used a PHP function as an example, but you might answer with any language example - which I guess even makes more sense if you consider PHP has its own set of tools for changing currency, formatting dates and numbers, etc.*

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: Always use `LC_MESSAGES`.

The `gettext` family of functions can only translate strings. It cannot magically convert dates, or format numerical values.

The most flexible function to retrieve translations with is `dcgettext(domainname, msgid, category)`, where `domainname` is your textdomain, `msgid` is the string you want to translate, and `category` is a locale category such as `LC_MESSAGES`. `dgettext(domainname, msgid)` uses the category `LC_MESSAGES`, and plain `gettext(msgid)` uses `LC_MESSAGES` and the textdomain you have set with `textdomain(domainname)` or the default textdomain "messages".

The rest of this answer is mostly an educated guess. Try it out and verify it if you can't help.

In order to determine the current locale, gettext does a `setlocale(category, NULL)`, where `category` is the third argument to `dcgettext`. If you invoke `dcgettext` with another category, for example `LC_NUMERIC`, it would probably use that category instead of `LC_MESSAGES`. So, if you have set `LC_MESSAGES` set to "de_DE" and `LC_NUMERIC` to "it_IT" it would probably search Italian translations.

The other aspect is the search path for translation files (`.mo` files). If you do a `bindtextdomain("yourtextdomain", "/usr/local/share/locale")`, the Italian translation file would be expected at "/usr/local/share/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES/yourtextdomain.mo". My guess is that the "LC_MESSAGES" would be replaced with "LC_NUMERIC". But again, I am not sure.

And remember, using any other locale category than `LC_MESSAGES` does not make sense, at least in my humble opinion.

Fun fact: `LC_MESSAGES` is part of POSIX but not a part of ANSI C. If the operating system does not define a value for `LC_MESSAGES`, GNU gettext uses 1729 instead.

Comment: One use case of LC_TIME being different than LC_MESSAGES is that it can be have a different date format than the interface language, for example en_US for interface language and en_GB for date/time format.